# Is there an idiomatic Ruby way to do "if" or "unless" based on a truth value?

Tags: ruby, idioms

I would like to run `x if y` if `z` is true, and `x unless y` if z is false.

What's the most idiomatic way to do that? The best I can come up with is:

```
x if z ? y : !y
```

Comment: I think what you have came up with is good enough and more readable than the other suggested alternatives. I would just modify it a little bit to become more readable: `x if (z ? y : !y)`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
x if !!y == !!z
```

This is a standard Ruby idiom for coercing to boolean values. If `y` and `z` are already booleans, then you can simply do:

```
x if y == z
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the xor operator, and then negate it:

```
x unless (!y ^ !z)
```

Corrected based on Victor suggestion, as things that aren't `true`, `false` or `nil` may do their own thing with `^`.

Comment: just as a precaution (Ruby is famous for using something other than `true` and `false`) I would rewrite it as `x unless(!y ^ !z)`

Comment: To put what Victor said more explicitly for those reading: Ruby allows anything to work as a truth value (i.e. anything other than nil or false counts as true), but this code depends on the implementation of the `^` operator found only in TrueClass, FalseClass and NilClass. This will fail unpredictably if `y` is something other than true, false or nil. So you need to ensure that you're working with booleans if you do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a confusing way of thinking about this. To me the clearer formulation (Ruby-ish or otherwise) is

```
x if (z and y) or (not z and not y)
```